# sorting data frame and creating new instantaneous column

Tags: r, dataframe, sorting, dplyr, group-by

I have a relatively large data frame (1.5 million rows and 5 columns). For simplicity, I created a sample data frame below:

```
date <- c("2018-07-06","2017-04-13","2017-09-12","2018-09-19"
          ,"2019-03-04","2017-05-21","2018-05-15")
data <- as.Date(date)
TV_ad<-c(0,1,0,0,1,0,1)
ID <- c(1315769,1300620,1300620,1315769,1300620,1315769,1300620)
result <- data.frame(ID,TV_ad,date)


       ID TV_ad       date
1 1315769     0 2018-07-06
2 1300620     1 2017-04-13
3 1300620     0 2017-09-12
4 1315769     0 2018-09-19
5 1300620     1 2019-03-04
6 1315769     0 2017-05-21
7 1300620     1 2018-05-15
```

what I want to do, for each specific ID, at the specific time, I want to calculate the ratio number of times that person used TV_ad on all **previous dates**. For this sample data set the result would be (the result is sorted by ID and date):

```
       ID TV_ad       date   ratio
1 1300620     1 2017-04-13      0
2 1300620     0 2017-09-12      1
3 1300620     1 2018-05-15     0.5
4 1300620     1 2019-03-04     0.66
5 1315769     0 2017-05-21      0
6 1315769     0 2018-07-06      0
7 1315769     0 2018-09-19      0
```

before 2017-04-13 there is no observation so ratio is 0, before 2017-09-12, there is one observation and TV_ad=1 so 1/1=1, before 2018-05-15 there is two observation and from those two we have TV_ad=1 for one of them so ratio is 1/2=0.5 and so on...
In another solution which was proposed by @det

```
library(dplyr)   

result %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ratio = cumsum(TV_ad) / seq_len(n()))
```

However, this solution takes the row we are at into account while I want to calculate the ratio up to the row we are doing calculation for.
I thought maybe we can use the following equation

```
ratio1 = (cumsum(TV_ad)) / seq_len(n()-1), ratio2=TV_ad/seq_len(n()-1))
```

and the subtract ratio 2 from ratio 1.

this solution works for all columns; however, for the first column of each group, since seq_len(n()==1 and 1-1=0, it returns NAN or an invalid number

Any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can calculate cumulative mean for each `ID` but since you don't want to include current date in the calculation you can `lag` it :

```
library(dplyr)

result %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ratio = lag(cummean(TV_ad), default = 0))

#     ID TV_ad date       ratio
#    <dbl> <dbl> <chr>      <dbl>
#1 1300620     1 2017-04-13 0    
#2 1300620     0 2017-09-12 1    
#3 1300620     1 2018-05-15 0.5  
#4 1300620     1 2019-03-04 0.667
#5 1315769     0 2017-05-21 0    
#6 1315769     0 2018-07-06 0    
#7 1315769     0 2018-09-19 0
```

The same concept can be applied to your current solution as well.

```
result %>%
  arrange(ID, date) %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(ratio = lag(cumsum(TV_ad) / seq_len(n()), default = 0))
```